# Using Isotop/jQUery to columinise posts on tumblr with infinite scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tumblr

Alrigghht so
It's the time old problem of script runs before images load and because it's tumblr, there's no way to get the image dimensions before it's loaded into the DOM...
http://glorymode.tumblr.com/

```
$('#thumbnails').infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : ".next a:last",
    nextSelector : ".next a:last",
    itemSelector : "#thumbnails .thumb",
    bufferPx : 7777,
    loadingText: "<span class=\"spectrum\" style=\"diaplay:none\">hold it, cowboy!</span>" },
    function(newElements){
        //$('#thumbnails').infinitescroll("pause");
        //$('.thumb', this).imagesLoaded( function(){
            //$(this).isotope({ animationEngine : 'none', itemSelector : '.thumb', layoutMode : 'masonry' });
            $(this).isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ), function() { /*$('#thumbnails').infinitescroll("resume")*/ } ); 
        //});
    }
);
```

isotope supposedly includes the *imagesLoaded* plugin... seems to do nothing though http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin

any assistance would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your infinite scroll callback

```
function(newElements){
  var $newElems = $(newElements);
  $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $('#thumbnails').isotope( 'appended', $newElems );
  });
}
```

You need to call imagesLoaded on the new Elements.